# Get a list of a dictionary's key names

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I make a function that takes a dictionary as input and outputs the *names* of its keys? So like:

```
input_dictionary = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
names = get_names(input_dictionary) # returns ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: `input_dictionary.keys()`

Comment: @idjaw a function :P. SO `def get_names(dic): return dic.keys()` :P.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realise there was native functionality built in. Should have read the docs more carefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for dictionaries (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for Python 3.5). There are multiple ways that this can be done.

You could use:

`input_dictionary.keys()`, obviously the easiest solution:

```
def get_names(input_dictionary):
    return input_dictionary.keys()
```

---

`input_dictionary.iterkeys()`, to get an iterator over the dictionary's keys, then you can iterate over those keys to create a list of them:

```
def get_names(input_dictionary):
    list_of_keys = []
    for key in input_dictionary.iterkeys():
        list_of_keys.append(key)
    return list_of_keys
```

---

`input_dictionary.iteritems()`, which returns an iterator over the dictionary's `(key, value)` pairs, which you can iterate over and then extract the keys:

```
def get_names(input_dictionary):
    list_of_keys = []
    for item in input_dictionary.iteritems():
        list_of_keys.append(item[0])
    return list_of_keys
```

---

`input_dictionary.popitem()`, which pops (removes) and returns an arbitrary `(key, value)` pair from your dictionary, from which you can extract the key. You probably don't want this one, though, since it clears your dictionary

---

And finally, `input_dictionary.viewitems()` or `input_dictionary.viewkeys()` to get a [*view*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) of the `(key, value)` pairs or the list of keys, respectively, for your dictionary. Anytime the dictionary changes, this view object will reflect that change.

Answer (score 2):

Using `keys()`:

```
>>> input_dictionary = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
>>> print input_dictionary.keys()
['foo', 'bar']
```

So a function would be:

```
def dictkeys(mydictionary):
    return mydictionary.keys()
```

Output:

```
>>> dictkeys(input_dictionary)
['foo', 'bar']
```

You don't really need a function for this though because it's the same as just simply using `dictionaryname.keys()`

Answer (score 2):

```
input_dictionary = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
input_dictionary.keys() # ["foo", "bar"]
```